# ImageDataGenerator Shape Issue

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am new to Keras. I am having some issues with shape while using ImageDataGenerator . Below is my code:

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(trainpath,target_size(227,227),classes=['class1','class2'])

x_train, y_train = next(train_batches)
```

When I print shape of x_train, it gives `(32, 227, 227, 3)`. I am not sure where "32" is coming in the shape. Because of this, I am having issues with training the model.

Any suggestion?

Comment: 32 is the batch size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is parameter that goes inside the method flow_from directory called batch_size, You can learn more about it here 

https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

So if you want to change the shape of the trainig batches generated, you can give a value for batch_size inside flow_from_directory()

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(trainpath,target_size(227,227),batch_size=64,classes=['class1','class2'])
```

The above code will generate batches of shape `(64,227,227,3)`. Hope this helps